# how to retrieve the list of contacts in android

Tags: android, json, contacts

my purpose to retrieve the list of contacts (name, number) is recorded in a json object, to send via web service to the server

then I found the code to visit contacts, and it is good, I test this code

```
String id, name;

        ContentResolver crs = getContentResolver();

        Cursor people = crs.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);



        String phone = "";

        people.moveToPosition(Contexts.getnbContacts());

        while (people.moveToNext())

        {

            id = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
            name = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(people.getString(people
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + id, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    // pdata =
                    // phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
                    phone = phone
                            + phones.getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA))
                            + " and ";
                    ;
                }

                phones.close();

            }
```

My question is: how to save each contact (name, number) in an array or arraylist ...

each table row designated contact

I think the array type is compatible with json format

so how to copy the contacts in a json object

Comment: [take a look at this , may help u..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylist-to-jsonarray)

Answer (score 4):

here my code

```
public static Map<String, String> getAddressBook(Context context)
{
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        int phone_idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int name_idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String phone = cursor.getString(phone_idx);
        String name = cursor.getString(name_idx);
        result.put(name, phone);
    }
    cursor.close();

    return result;
}
```

and need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to retrieve the favourite contacts from Contacts DB

```
Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, "starred=?",new String[] {"1"}, null);
```

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-favorite-contacts/201/251004?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~