# Get All mobile numbers Stored in Android device programatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to **get all the mobile numbers and details(forexample operator name) of each mobile number stored in my Android device**.and display in ListView ,Any Idea how can achieve this?

Comment: You can look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124034/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-contacts-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        this.getAllMobileNumbers( this );

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getAllMobileNumbers( final Context context ) {
        final ArrayList<String> listNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null );
        while ( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
            final int phone_id = cursor.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER );
            final String phone = cursor.getString( phone_id );
            listNumbers.add( phone );
        }

        return listNumbers;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get provider name ?