# ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI vs ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-query

In [how to retrieve the list of contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124034/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-contacts-in-android) I see code that allows you to read contacts using either `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` or `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`.

What is the difference between them?

When can they be different?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ContactsContract.Contacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) to query *just* **Contacts** and [`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) can be used to query for details like **Phone Numbers** if you have the ID of a contact.

Be sure to add `.CONTENT_URI` at the end of the Constant and check the documentation for more information.