# How to save Android ArrayList into Mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that I want to save into MySql database using restapi from my server. I create the `ArrayList` from value of checked item in `ListView`.

After populate the data I insert the `ArrayList` into a single column in `MySql` using Fast Android Networking (FAN) Library. Upon inserting I convert the `ArrayList` into string using `toString()` method.

The problem is the saved `ArrayList` is not in the format I expected it to be. It saved in format like this:

`"[jon, doe, jane, doe]"`

What I want is the ArrayList is save in this format:

`["jon", "doe", "jane", "doe"]`

Please help me how to do it.

Comment: If i understand you problem correctly, you need need convert your ArrayList to JSON string. Look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylistmycustomclass-to-jsonarray.

Comment: nice, thank you for the answer. Now the inserted value looks like this       
"[\"123\",\"456\"]" how to remove the doublequote outside the bracket?

Comment: Now when you want get the data from DB and use in your app you need do the reverse operation - convert JSON string to ArrayList. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist.

Comment: But unfortunately, what my user will do next will be occured in web server, not in android apps

Comment: What are you using in backend of the web server ? PHP, nodeJS, Python ?

Comment: PHP with Laravel as Framework.

Comment: Hey, how can I tag your comment as an answer. I figured it out now. thanks for your help.