# How to store records in a HashMap or ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a general question about HashMaps vs. ArrayLists.

Ian a project I am working on I am scanning a barcode from a ticket, like entering a ballpark or concert.

As part of this scan there is also static information that the user has pre-selected, like userName, location. I also capture the Date and time of when the barcode is scanned. So I end up with a record consisting of Date/Time, userName,location,barcode scanned.

I need to store this information for 100 to 200 scans, then at the end of the day, convert this to a JSON object.

I am a bit confused on how to store this data. Can someone give me some pointers on this? I have googled it but am still confused.

Thanks much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Create an object to wrap the Date/Time, name, location, and barcode. You could store these in an ArrayList<YourObject>, since it doesn't sound like you plan on doing any manipulations to the data. Then you can reference other questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylistmycustomclass-to-jsonarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not solely keeping this  records to a hashmap or arraylist in memory. Maybe the phone will turn off or your application will crash. So the user will lose everything stored in memory so far.

What I would do is this. I would create a DTO object with the fields you want eg:

```
public class MyDTO{
    private String field1;
    private LocalDateTime field2;
    [...]

}
```

Then each object when created use `Gson` or whatever you like and store it as json either to a db or a file(s).

At the end of the day read the saved json objects. Combine them to an ArrayList of MyDTOs and use `Gson` to create an array of json and send them.

After you have successfully submitted the JSON just clean up the db or file(s).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I came to the same conclusion after posting this question. I need permanent storage and since I have 8 pieces of information to store for each data scan I figure I will use SQLite database along with a helper class. Now to go learn that! :)