# android : converting ArrayList to JSON and post to a url

Tags: android

**hello dear friends ,In my project i have an arraylist that filling from beacons data every second , is it possible to convert this arrayL to  JSONArray and post it to an URL at the same time ??? **

```
'private ArrayList<Beacon> arrayL = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    arrayL.clear();
                    arrayL.addAll((ArrayList<Beacon>) iBeacons);

                }
            });
        }
    });'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVFFd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert ArrayList<MyCustomClass> to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylistmycustomclass-to-jsonarray)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that:

1) Build the JSON object

```
ArrayList<Beacon> arrayL = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(arrayL));
```

2) Post to server

```
public void postData() {
    ArrayList<String> arrayL = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(arrayL));
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mJSONArray.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject objects = mJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Iterate through the elements of the array i.
        //Get thier value.
        //Get the value for the first element and the value for the last element.
    }
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        outputBytes = json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = connection.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        os.write(outputBytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.