# How to convert ArrayList to JSONArray() in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a list in my POJO class:

```
"userQuoteTravellers": [ 
     {
        "id": 1354,
        "quoteId": 526,
        "travellerId": null
     }
]
```

I want to pass this list as it is in `JSONArray` and passing it as:

```
JSONArray.put(list)
```

It is being sent as:

> "userQuoteTravellers": [ "[]" ]

But I want to send it as

> "userQuoteTravellers": []

How can I achieve this in Kotlin without using any loop?

Comment: have a look https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/send-json-post-req-with-json-array-and-multiple-json-object-in-volley/11034

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert ArrayList<MyCustomClass> to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylistmycustomclass-to-jsonarray)

Comment: I dont want to use any loop @animusmind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`put` adds the list as an element to the `JSONArray`. Thats not what you want. You want your `JSONArray` to represent the list.

`JSONArray` offers a constructor for that:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(listOf(1, 2, 3))
```

---

But there is a much easier way. You don't need to worry about single properties. Just pass the whole POJO.

Let's say you have this:

```
class QuoteData(val id: Int, val quoteId: Int, travellerId: Int?)
class TravelerData(val userQuoteTravellers: List<QuoteData>)

val travelerData = TravelerData(listOf(QuoteData(1354, 546, null)))
```

You just have to pass `travelerData` to the `JSONArray` constructor:

```
val travelerDataJson = JSONArray(travelerData)
```

and it will be represented like this:

> "userQuoteTravellers": [
>       {
>           "id": 1354,
>           "quoteId": 526,
>           "travellerId": null
>       }  ]

Answer (score 6):

**With Dependencies**

Add to your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Convert ArrayList to JsonArray

```
val jsonElements = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree(itemsArrayList)
```

**Without Dependencies**

```
val jsonElements = JSONArray(itemsArrayList)
```

Comment: Is this using the same JSON library as the original question is asking about?

Comment: Yes, But If you don't want to use library than default is val jsArray = JSONArray(mylist). Just pass your generic array list to JSONArray arguments

Comment: Here JSONArray is come from Collection only. No need to add library for that

Comment: @KalpeshRupani No, it will not solve my problem because I have already tried in the same way. Read the question again.

Answer (score 3):

If I read the JSONArray constructors correctly, you can build them from any Collection (arrayList is a subclass of Collection) like so:

```
val list = ArrayList<String?>()
list.add("jigar")
list.add("patel")
val jsArray = JSONArray(list)
```

You can also use GSON for read json see below example:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
class userQuoteTravellers {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("quoteId")
    @Expose
    var quoteId: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("travellerId")
    @Expose
    var travellerId: Any? = null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`val userQuote = response.getJSONArray("userQuoteTravellers")`

then call the data inside like this:

```
for (i in 0 until userQuote.length()) {
    val quotes = userQuote.getJSONObject(i)
    // then call the other data here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using this

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'


  var gson = Gson()
  var jsonData = gson.toJson(PostPojo::class.java)
```